# UpdateOne MongoDB with push using value from another field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to push an existing field of my document to my array. this is my schema :

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    level: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },
    mHierarchy: [
        {
            userId: {
                  type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId
            },
            index: {
                  type: Number
            }
         }
    ]
})
```

i'm trying to use UpdateOne and push to mHierarchy and set outer level to the index.

what I've tried so far:

```
MySchema.updateOne(
{'_id': mySchemaId},
$push: {
        referredHierarchy: {
                        userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
                        index: '$$level'
                        }
        }
)}
```

I also tried this:

```
let setQuery= {}
setQuery['mHierarchy.' + level + '.userId']= mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
setQuery['mHierarchy.' + level + '.index']= '$$temp'
MySchema.updateOne(
                    {'_id': mySchemaId},
                    {
                        $set: setQuery
                    },
                    {let: {temp: '$level'}}
                )
```

and none of the above works and I get this error :

```
"CastError: Cast to Number failed for value \"$$temp\" (type string) at path \"index\""
```

how can I achieve this using mongoose?

NOTE: I use MongoDB 5 and "mongoose": 6.0.8

Comment: To update a field with another field value of the same document, you can use Update with Aggregation Pipeline feature (MongoDB v4.2 or higher).

Comment: I wanted to increment `level` but for simplicity, I removed it. your answer is correct if I don't use `$inc` operation,`$inc` is not defined in Pipeline. thank you.

Comment: Use `$add` aggregate operator to increment by  a value.

Comment: @prasad_ can you test your solution or post your answer? I tried PipeLine without using `$add` and `@inc` but I couldn't push it to my array in the right way.

Comment: The `$inc` cannot be used in a pipeline  (it is an error). You need to use the [$add Aggregate Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/).

Comment: @prasad_ I understand that. I tried without `$inc` but I couldn't implement it. I asked you if you can show me some code and examples with Pipeline so I understand my problem.

Comment: I have already included the link to the `$add` aggregation operator (it is the documentation and examples in MongoDB Manual). _I don''t see any code that you have tried with the operator or the pipeline._ The update method needs to use a pipeline also.

Comment: @prasad_ I have to use `$push` to add it to the array. and aggregation Pipeline can not accept `$push`. I tried `$set` to index (with pipeline), but it's not working.

Comment: Inside pipleline you can use `$concatArrays` - its an aggregate operator. _Note that inside pipeline, you can use aggregate operators only (not the update operators)_.

Comment: @prasad_ I finally got it. if you can submit your answer, I can accept it for others to use.
thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You will need first to add this field to the pipeline with the $set operator. Try this one:

```
MySchema.updateOne({ _id: mySchemaId }, {
$set: {
  index: "$level",
}},{
$push: {
  referredHierarchy: {
    userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
    index: "$index",
  },
}});
```

Try another workaround for test reasons:

```
MySchema.updateMany({ _id: mySchemaId },[{
$addFields: {
  index: "$level",
}},{
$push: {
  referredHierarchy: {
    index: "$index",
  },
}}]);
```

updateOne doesn't accept pipeline aggregation operators so try with this updateMany for testing.

Comment: I get this error : `MongooseError: Invalid update pipeline operator: "$push"`

Comment: Try my last edit.

Comment: still not working, although I think your code has a bug based on your `{` and `}`.you used `$push` in `option` instead of `update`.

Comment: updateOne CAN accept pipeline aggregation. the point is that pipeline aggregation CAN NOT accept `$push`. 
thank you for your answer, I tried it and not work with the same error